# Purpose of Using Filegroup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand about the purpose of using Filegroup in SQL server? What benefit can it provide?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544898/sql-server-2005-2008-multiple-filegroups

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Enterprise Edition, you can do a piecemeal restore. That is, you can place critical and not-so-critical tables on different filegroups and, in the case of disaster, recover them at different times. This requires a lot of forethought, but is handy.